# npm globally installed package. command not found on zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to install the npm package @wicked/cli using the command

```
npm install @wicked/cli -g
```

The output I'm getting indicates that the package has been updated, which means it was already installed.

However, when I tried running the command wicked-cli, I get the following error

```
zsh: command not found: wicked-cli
```

Am I missing something ? is there a path I need to add to the $Path? I've just updated my mac os a couple of days ago and not really familiar with zsh

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command is just called `wicked` and not `wicked-cli`

Try run `wicked --help`

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wicked-cli